# Changing value of layer attribute based on geometrical conditions of line elements through ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor, feature-layer

I have a feature class layer that comprise of line elements. For my purpose, I needed the start and end point coordinates of each line, so I added new columns with *add field* and use *calculate geometry* in ArcGIS Pro to assign the start/end coordinates to each line (below table show the attributes).

What I want to do is that to write a python code that compare lines’ first and end coordinates. Then return a `list` of `ID`s for those that their start/end points are equal, and append all those as nested lists in a main list. For instance, if object `ID`s 2, 5 and 6 have same start and end point, and if object `ID`s 8, 12, 15 an 22 have the same condition, the code return a nested list like this: `main_list = [[2, 5, 6], [8, 12, 15, 22]]`. Finally, I want to edit the `var` column with this outcome. I want `var` to be equal to length of each corresponding nested list minus one. For instance for those example above, `var` values for object `ID`s 2, 5 and 6 will be 2 (length of nested list minus one), and for `ID`s 8, 12, 15 and 22 will be 3.

| ID | x_start | y_start | x_end | y_end | var |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| . |  |  |  |  |  |
| . |  |  |  |  |  |

```
fields = ['ID', 'x_start', 'y_start', 'x_end', 'y_end']
MainList   = [[]]
NestedList = []

ID = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Redundancy_one, ('ID'))]
x_start = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Redundancy_one, ('x_start'))]
y_start = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Redundancy_one, ('y_start'))]
x_end = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Redundancy_one, ('x_end'))]
y_end = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Redundancy_one, ('y_end'))]

i = 0
while i<len(ID):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor[Redundancy_one, fields] as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if x_start[0] == row[1] and y_start[2] == row[2] and x_end[2] == row[3] and y_end == row[4] and ID[0] =! row[0]:
                NestedList.append(ID[0])
                NestedList.append (row[0])
    MainList.append(NestedList)
    NestedList=[]
    i +=1
```

Comment: Have you considered the use of the FindIdentical tool? Example 4 takes you most of the the way there.
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/find-identical.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pandas and arcpy together

```
#Create a pandas dataframe from your line layer with the columns ID and the line geometry
import pandas as pd
layer = 'lines_starting_ending_same'
fields = ["ID","SHAPE@"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer, fields), columns=["id","line"])

#Calculate start and end coordinates for all lines
df["start_x"]=df.apply(lambda x: x.line.firstPoint.X, axis=1)
df["start_y"]=df.apply(lambda x: x.line.firstPoint.Y, axis=1)
df["end_x"]=df.apply(lambda x: x.line.lastPoint.X, axis=1)
df["end_y"]=df.apply(lambda x: x.line.lastPoint.Y, axis=1)

#Group lines having the same start and end coordinates and list their ids
same_start_and_end = df.groupby(["start_x","start_y","end_x","end_y"])["id"].apply(list).reset_index()

#Count them
same_start_and_end["count"] = same_start_and_end.apply(lambda x: len(x["id"]), axis=1)
same_start_and_end["var"] = same_start_and_end["count"]-1

#Then do whatever you want with the result. For example export as a table, or update the values in your lines table
```

[image]

To create a field in the original table with the calculated var value. Create a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and use it with [da.UpdateCursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm):

```
#Create a dictionary with id as key and var as value
update_dict = dict(zip(same_start_end["id"], same_start_end["var"]))
update_dict

#Add an integer field called var
table = r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\lines_starting_ending_same.shp"
arcpy.management.AddField(in_table=table, field_name="var", field_type="SHORT")
#Update it using the dictionary
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, ["id","var"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in update_dict:
            row[1] = update_dict[row[0]]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: always enjoy reading your responses as I end up learning something new about python.  I don't use pandas but have been trying to understand your answer. I guess this is obvious to a pandas user, but looking at your code you create the XY coordinates of the end points using code `df["start_x"]=df.apply...`. What I can't get my head around is where is "start_x", you don't seem to have created that before you populate it with data? Is this a behaviour of pandas, if you reference a field name that does not exist in the data frame it is simultaneously created and populated?

Comment: :). .Yes that is the standard way of creating a new column. Pandas is great, you can do almost anything with the data. A thing like that, creating a new column is very simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @BERA. I was wondering why the length of initial and final my data frame is different. I had 859 before using the code but 783 after that? I guess there shouldn't be any differences.

Comment: It should be beacuse of the grouping. In my example the three rows 1,2,3 become one. If you want the same row count you can [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

Comment: Hey @BERA. I just wondering if you could help me finish this task completely. Only final steps remains. I wanted to update a variable on my attribute table based on **var** value. I need to update **var** values for each **id** in my main layer. Really appreciate this. I mostly work on QGIS and new to ArcGIS.

Comment: Yes, see the update